# Where is path set for non-interactive ssh user authenticated using LDAP?

Tags: macos, ssh, ldap, ldap-client

There is a Mac on our network (let's call it MACHINE) that is configured to do LDAP authentication.  There is no local user named USER on this Mac, but there is a user named USER known to the LDAP server.

When I execute this command from my Mac:

```
ssh USER@MACHINE echo \$PATH
```

where is that path being loaded from?

(notice the path I get that way is quite different from if I do the ssh, open a remote session, and then type echo $PATH)

There are a lot of places that the path *isn't* being loaded from (I know this because they specify paths that don't appear in the actual \$PATH):

```
/etc/paths
/etc/paths.d
/etc/bashrc
```

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

There is usually a template user account provided by a Unix'y system, and I am pretty sure it will include a path in it.  Usually that would be `etc/skel`.

On the Mac it is: 
`/System/Library/User\ Template/`